# Ember: controller properties not available in partial views - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ember.js

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/aYmuJ/3/

I set a property in the application controller and want to display this property in a partial view. This does not seem to work.  I can access the property in the template itself, but not in the partial view rendered within the template ..

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h3>Ember access to controller properties</h3>
    {{#linkTo 'about'}}About{{/linkTo}} <br><br>
    {{outlet}} 
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    Access to property in index template: <br>
    <b>{{controllers.application.applicationVersion}}</b> 
    <br><br>     
    {{render "_footer"}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_footer">
    Footer text (partial view) with a controller property:<br>
    <b>{{controllers.application.applicationVersion}} MISSING</b>
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('about', { path: "/about" });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
    this.transitionTo('about');
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  //Set some properties
  applicationVersion: "1.0.0"
});

App.AboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: "application"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render` view helper have your own context.
To use the current context in a other template use the `partial` view helper.

```
{{partial "footer"}}
```

When you use `render` a new controller is created, in that case named `generated _footer controller`.

Using `partial` will preserve the controller bound to the template that called the partial template

And since you used `needs` in about controller, you don't have it in the new generated controller.

Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/2FkgY/)

Comment: OK. Was not aware that there is this difference between render and partial.